# How to center jquery ui buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Adding this to CSS does not work:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonpane { text-align: center; }
```

The buttons are still on the right side.

What should I do?

Comment: inspected the button style in firebug? have you given !important?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok. I also needed to remove the float. This works:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { 
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { 
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { text-align: center; float: none; } also works ok, good answer...

Answer (score 4):

In my case I also needed to add !important to the float property

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    text-align: center;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following two classes need to be modified:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpan{
text-align: center !important
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none !important;
}
```