# Centering buttons inside a div of JqueryUI

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI. Created a dialog. Inside the dialog I have a div. Inside that Div I have two buttons "Delete" and "Cancel". I have been trying middling the buttons into the center of the div. Used DOM explorer to find the class of the div and tried changing there in the class. But still it is not happening. I am sharing my code below.

```
<link href="Themes/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    <div id="dialog-confirm">
    </div>
```

Comment: I do not understand what it is you are trying to do.  Each dialog button simply closes the dialog.  What are the buttons in the DIV you mentioned?

Comment: share the html of the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the buttons' div by using `.ui-dialog-buttonset`. This could lead to problems if you have multiple dialogs on your page, in which case you'll have to find some way of injecting a class into them.

By default this is given `float: right` which you'll want to replace with `float: none` you'll also want to use a width and `margin: 0 auto` to center it.
So put the following in your css:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset{
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 205px;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLovxpyv/), showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following style to acheive the centering of buttons:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {float: none; text-align:center;}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset button{margin-left:1em;margin-right:1em;}
```

If this isn't enough jquery for you then you could always do it by adding these lines in the javascript after your dialog call:

```
$(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset").css("float", "none").css("text-align", "center");
$(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset button").css("margin-left", "1em").css("margin-right", "1em");
```

Tested in Firefox only btw...

Source: [How to center jquery ui buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689890/how-to-center-jquery-ui-buttons)